# Python: Scapy Selector List Size increases calling text()

Tags: python, css, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm looking to extract a list of document names `['document 1', 'document 2', 'document x']` from some html:

```
<div class = "pdf_download">
<a href="https://example.com/document1.pdf">
    <img alt="Download PDF" src="download.jpg">
    Document 1
</a>
</div>
<div class = "pdf_download">
<a href="https://example.com/document2.pdf">
    <img alt="Download PDF" src="download.jpg">
    Document 2
</a>
</div>
```

When I try using both css and xpath selectors, the two  tags create a list of four, presumably because of the `<img>` tags which I can't seem to exclude:

```
response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'pdf')]/text()").extract()
# returns an empty list
# response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'pdf')]/*[not(self::img)]/text()").extract()
response.css(".pdf_download a:not(img)::text()").extract()
```

Output:

```
[\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t,
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t,Document 1\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t,
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t,
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t,Document 2\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t]
```

Using CSS or Xpath selectors, is there a way of extracting out a list of the document names?

Comment: `.re(r'[^\s].*')`?

Comment: Thanks, does the trick in this instance. Updated the question to reflect it, but ideally this should be done using selectors, as sometimes there are other tags whose text is being included when it shouldn't.

Comment: Then ask about such a case :)